# rails tailwind css - cannot get two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I can't get two columns using Tailwind CSS. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

My rails code

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4"> 
    <div class="col-span-1">sidebar</div>
    <div class="col-span-5"><%= yield %></div>
</div>
```

[image]

When I try the same code in tailwind playground, i get the expected result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run `rails tailwindcss:build`.

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, it is always good to explicitly state that. And please - even if it may feel strange - mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @soundflix I think they have to [wait 2 days or something before accepting a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Will mark this accepted tonight